# How to wait for page reload with selenium?

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

Consider the following code:

```
$this->visit('/');
$text = $this->byCssSelector('.some-element')->text();
$this->byCssSelector('.some-link')->click();
# how do I wait for a new page to be loaded here?
$this->assertEquals($text, $this->byCssSelector('.some-element')->text());
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=selenium+php+wait --> https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/wiki/HowTo-Wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see on the web, executing javascript is to be avoided if possible, so I came up with non-javascript solution:

```
$this->visit('/');
$text = $this->byCssSelector('.some-element')->text();
$this->waitForPageReload(function () {
    $this->byCssSelector('.some-link')->click();
}, 5000);
$this->assertEquals($text, $this->byCssSelector('.some-element')->text());

function waitForPageReload($navigate_f, $timeout) {
    $id = $this->byCssSelector('html')->getId();
    call_user_func($navigate_f);
    $this->waitUntil(function () use ($id) {
        $html = $this->byCssSelector('html');
        if ($html->getId() != $id)
            return TRUE;
    }, $timeout);
}
```

Inspired by this [great article](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-page-load-after-a-click.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can set(via js call) `window.is_old_page = true`, and checking until this will be `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you can use the sleep function:

```
sleep($seconds);
```

Comment: A straight road to flaky tests. What would those cases be?

Comment: Sure. But for a performance test it looks good for me. For example to be sure that a response time is not terrible.